# How to drag and drop items over bounds of the horizontal recyclerview with ItemTouchHelper.Callback?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I want to drag items over my horizontal recyclerview(not only within bounds of the recyclerview) and when drop an item it goes to new position with animation. How to achieve this using ItemTouchHelper.Callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might avoid using `ItemTouchHelper` to achieve your goal. See [my code on GitHub](https://github.com/jkozh/DragDropTwoRecyclerViews) for more information.

[image]